# How to submit 2 forms in one page with a single submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a php page with two forms but I would like to have only one submit button for both forms. the forms have the `id`s `firstform` & `secondform`. I have tried other scripts but they don't really work.

Here is my code below:

```
<script language="javascript">
submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("firstform").submit();
    document.getElementById("secondform").submit();
}

</script>

<input type="image" src="images/order-button.png" name="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForms()"/>
```

Comment: have you tried to `return false` from `submitForms`?

Comment: @DanielA.White no i didnt try, but where to put return false

Comment: Nuh-uh. Submitting forwards you to the action URL unless it sends back somethings which is not intended to be shown by the browser (a file you can download).
You could use javascript to send an ajax post message containing data in each form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have SEVERAL issues

1. input type=image IS a submit button so you are trying to submit something from a non-existing form, likely the same page you are on
2. when you submit form1, it replaces the current page, if you manage to submit form2 as well, it is VERY likely to interfere with the submission of form1

Here is what you can TRY (plain javascript):

```
<script language="javascript">
function submitForms() {
  document.getElementById("firstform").submit();
  document.getElementById("secondform").submit();
 }
</script>

<form id="firstform" target="iframe1">
</form><iframe name="iframe1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<form id="secondform" target="iframe2">
</form><iframe name="iframe1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<button typ"button" onclick="submitForms()"><img src="images/order-button.png" "/></button>
```

Alternatively AJAX the forms one at a time (assumes jQuery loaded)

[DEMO HERE](http://plungjan.name/test/duosubmit.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subbut").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // or make the button type=button
    $.post($("#firstform").attr("action"), $("#firstform").serialize(), function() {
      $.post($("#secondform").attr("action"), $("#secondform").serialize(),
        function() {
          alert('Both forms submitted');
        });
    });
  });
});
```

---

UPDATE: If you want two form's content to be submitted to one action, just add the serialises:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subbut").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // or make the button type=button
    $.post($("#firstform").attr("action"), $("#firstform").serialize() + $("#secondform").serialize(), function() {
      alert('Both forms submitted');
    });
  });
});
```

PS: The PHP in the demo is just echoing back what you post. There is no special action needed on the server.

Comment: _mplungjan_ i try both & when i place submit button in first form only its working, when i place submit button in second form then only second form working but when i place submit button out side both form then nothing working

Answer (score 3):

- Set the "target" attribute on the first form to "_blank"
- Set the "action" attribute on the first form to "#close" (replace "close" with whatever you want.
- Have a script on the page that checks if the document.location.hash is "close" if it is window.close()

Here's the jsfiddle to demonstrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/TqhPr/18/

HTML

```
<form id="f1" name="f1" target="_blank" method="POST" action="#close">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" id="s1" value="11" />
</form>
<hr/>
<form id="f2" name="f2" method="POST" action="#second_form">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" id="s2" value="22" />
</form>
<hr/>
<input type="button" id="both" value="Submit Both Forms" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#both").click(function() {
        document.getElementById("f1").submit();
        document.getElementById("f2").submit();
    });
    if(document.location.hash == "#close") {
        alert("closing the window caused by posting the first form");
        window.close();
    }
    if(document.location.hash) {
        alert(document.location.hash);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "submitted separately" Please be more elaborate in your comments

Comment: _mplungjan_ when i click on 11 button it give me value 1 and same on button 22, but when i click on "Submit Both Forms" it donot work

Answer (score 0):

I used this for a similar problem. I wanted to create a single page to query multiple sites and review their results side-by-side:
WordLookup.html (main/home/frame entry point):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Word Lookup</title>
  </head>
  <frameset cols="33%,34%,33%">
    <frame src="" name="DIC">
    <frameset rows="21,*">
      <frame src="frame.html" name="PRF">
      <frame src="" name="MW">
    </frameset>
    <frame src="" name="TFD">
  </frameset>
</html>
```

and then this for frame.html (javascript method):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body { margin: 0; background-color: #AAAAAA; }
  table, td { padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
  form { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
</style>
<script>
  function submitForms(){
    var x = document.getElementById("search3").value;
    document.getElementById("fr1").setAttribute("value", x);
    document.getElementById("DIC").submit();
    document.getElementById("fr2").setAttribute("value", x);
    document.getElementById("MW").submit();
    document.getElementById("fr3").setAttribute("value", x);
    document.getElementById("TFD").submit();
    document.getElementById("search3").value = "";
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="search3" type="text" placeholder="3x Search" onclick="value=''" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)
{submitForms()}" autofocus="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="http://www.dictionary.com/dic" target="DIC" id="DIC">
          <input id="fr1" name="q" type="hidden" placeholder="Dictionary" onclick="value=''">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary" target="MW" id="MW">
          <input id="fr2" name="s" type="hidden" placeholder="Merriam-Webster" onclick="value=''">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="//www.thefreedictionary.com/_/search.aspx" target="TFD" id="TFD">
          <input id="fr3" name="word" type="hidden" placeholder="TheFreeDictionary" onclick="value=''">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if this is a little wordy but it's a working example (in chrome 56ish).

Answer (score -1):

This code successfully posted 2 forms data with single submit button.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
/* Collect all forms in document to one and post it */
function submitAllDocumentForms() {
    var arrDocForms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    var formCollector = document.createElement("form");
    with(formCollector)
    {
        method = "post";
        action = "test.php";
        name = "formCollector";
        id = "formCollector";
    }
    for(var ix = 0 ; ix < arrDocForms.length ; ix++) {
        appendFormVals2Form(arrDocForms[ix], formCollector);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(formCollector);
    formCollector.submit();
}

/* Function: add all elements from frmCollectFrom and append them to 
             frmCollector before returning frmCollector*/
function appendFormVals2Form(frmCollectFrom, frmCollector) {
    var frm = frmCollectFrom.elements;
    for(var ix = 0 ; ix < frm.length ; ix++)
        frmCollector.appendChild(frm[ix]);
    return frmCollector;
}
</SCRIPT>

<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="test.php" NAME="form1" id="form1">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="box1" size="20" >
</FORM>
FORM2:
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="test.php" NAME="form2" id="form2">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="box2" size="20" >
</FORM>

<INPUT TYPE="button" value="Submit Form 1 & 2" onClick="submitAllDocumentForms()">
```

Comment: Great - that is not what you asked. You asked to submit two forms and not how to concatenate two forms into one submit. See my update

Comment: _mplungjan_ yes your demo is also perfect & many thanks for that :)