# Submit two forms sequentially with AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm trying to implement the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096515/how-to-submit-2-forms-in-one-page-with-a-single-submit-button) thread, however I've never used AJAX.

The first form sets a variable required in the second form, once this has been set I'd like it to then redirect as per the second form (so I'm guessing the alert wants to come out of the AJAX?)
After updating with charles babbage's answer the first form Submits.

Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subbut").click(function() {
        $.post($("#priceselect").attr("action"), $("#priceselect").serialize(),
          function() {
            $.post($("#globaliris").attr("action"), $("#globaliris").serialize(),
              function() {
                alert('Both forms submitted');
              });
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

I've put this in the head with the aim of first submitting

```
<form name="priceselect" id="priceselect" method="post">
  <select name="price" id="mySelect" onchange="document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML = this.value;">
    <option value="100">Option 1</option>
    <option value="120">Option 2</option>
    <option value="115">Option 3</option>
    <option value="135">Option 4</option>
    <option value="80" >Option 5</option>
  </select>
<input value="Continue" id="subbut" type="Submit" />
</form>
```

which should then

```
(isset($_POST['price']));
$price = $_POST['price'];
```

in the same page before redirecting to a 3rd party with the submission of

```
<form id="globaliris" action="https://redirect.globaliris.com/epage.cgi" method="post" class="select">

<input type=hidden name="MERCHANT_ID" value="<?=$merchantid?>">
<input type=hidden name="ORDER_ID" value="<?=$orderid?>">
<input type=hidden name="CURRENCY" value="<?=$curr?>">
<input type=hidden name="AMOUNT" value="<?=$amount?>">
<input type=hidden name="TIMESTAMP" value="<?=$timestamp?>">
<input type=hidden name="MD5HASH" value="<?=$md5hash?>">
<input type=hidden name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
<br />
<br />
</form>
```

Comment: What is not working? Change `type` attribute of "subbut" input to "button".

Comment: Nothing's happening, I've tried changing the input to button, with no luck unfortunately! @Igor Thanks for helping

Comment: Form "priceselect" does not have "action" attribute. Any error in the console?

Comment: @Igor I've tried setting it to action="#" with no change. I don't get any error messages unfortunately, simply nothing happens on pressing the button. I've added the POST that's on the same page as these two forms in the edit

Comment: have you imported the jQuery library at the top of your page?

Comment: How is having `$.post("#", ...` helping you? Set form's action attribute to a valid url.

Comment: @Igor The first form Submits to the page it's on, whilst the second redirects and stays there. I've tried adding the action to be the URL of this page, with no differnce. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger the **action** that you have specified in the Form tag on click of a button, the button should be of type Submit and also it should be inside your form. The position of Submit button is **important**.

```
  <input type="submit" value="something" id="something">
```

**Edit(as per your new question)**

If you want two form's content to be submitted to one action, just add the serialises as below:

```
      $.post($("#priceselect").attr("action"),$("#priceselect").serialize()+$("#globaliris").serialize() ,
          function() {
            alert('Both forms submitted');
          });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've edited the post and my code accordingly, it now Submits the first form, but doesn't redirect/submit the second (it shouldn't return on the after the second form submission)

Comment: why dont you try putting the invocation of second form in the success method of first Ajax call?

Comment: The first form submits because you put a submit button inside it - the whole page is refreshed. The `$post` call still does not work.

Comment: @charlesbabbage - he does not want to submit both forms in one action - the forms are supposed to be submitted to different urls.

Comment: The first form is meant to submit to the page it's on whilst the second is supposed to redirect, if that helps?