# Send two forms with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to send two forms with the click of one button.
This script work in Firefox and Internet Explorer but not in Chrome and Safari.

```
<form action="linkweb" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
</form>

<form action="unoamoltissl.php" method="post" id="form2" style="width:450px;margin-left:-10px;">
</form>

<input type="button" value="" onclick="submitForms();" style="background-image:url('images/sharenow.png');width:200px;height:60px;background-repeat:no-repeat;border:none;margin-left:35px;"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    submitForms = function() {
        if (form2.User_Email.value.length == 0, form2.Friend_Email.value.length == 0, form2.Friend_Email_Terzo.value.length == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML = "* Please complete all the 3 fields to share.";
        }
        else if (form2.User_Email.value.length != 0, form2.Friend_Email.value.length != 0, form2.Friend_Email_Terzo.value.length != 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("mc-embedded-subscribe-form").submit();
            document.getElementById("form2").submit();
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I updated the code with this, but now work only the second form not the first:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#subbut").click(function() {
    $.post($("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").attr("action"), $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").serialize(),
      function() {
        $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize(),
          function() {
             location.href = 'index2.html';
          });
      });
  });
```

});

```
<button id="subbut" onclick="submitForms();" style="background-image:url('images/sharenow.png');width:200px;height:60px;background-repeat:no-repeat;border:none;margin-left:35px;"/></button>
```

I checked with the console of chrome and the result is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: isset is not defined (index):603submitForms (index):603onclick (index):446
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined (index):421onsubmit (index):421

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096515/how-to-submit-2-forms-in-one-page-with-a-single-submit-button

Comment: Take a look at your `if` conditions. There should be `&&` instead of `,` between conditions. `form2.User_Email.value.length == 0 && form2.Friend_Email.value.length == 0` and so on. Right now `if` decision is based on last condition.

Comment: ok i changed the code, but now doesn't work, start only one form (the form2) the first is ignored

Comment: something is terribly wrong, i can assume it by just reading the title.

Comment: is the first form ignored (did you verify this by looking at the Network console), or maybe you have a server-side issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this code, I hope can help other people

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post" id="form2" name="f2" style="width:450px;margin-left:-10px;"></form>

<form action="test1.php" method="post" id="form1" name="f1" style="width:450px;margin-left:-10px;"></form>

<input type="button" onClick="runscript();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function runscript() {
    document.forms.f1.submit();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.forms.f2.submit();
    }, 100);

    }
</script>
```

regards

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

What happens if the first form post errors?  You only have a callback for success..

Maybe it's worth using $ajax instead so you can define (and detect) what happens if the first post failes .. at least while diagnosing the issue, anyway :

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
error: error,
dataType: dataType
});