# Form submission minor issue

Tags: html

I have a form like this. I want to know that will the form submission work if the  is placed in the middle of the text fields?

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="fname"> // First Name
<input type="text" name="lname"> // Last Name
<form method="post" action="">   // Post 
<input type="text" name="username"> // Username
<input type="text" name="password"> // Password
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> // Submit Button
```

Will the submission work for First Name and Last Name field as the  is after them so they do not come inside the form.

Comment: Where do you close your `</form>`tag ?

Comment: after the submit button.. sorry forgot to mention that..

Comment: No it will take only username and password fields, since only these two fields are included between the form tags

Comment: Big no, but you can do it with jQuery and put hidden inputs inside the form.

Comment: how can I submit 2 forms with 1 submit button?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you explain why you can't just move the opening <form> tag before your fname and lname inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Your form elements (like your input boxes) have to be between an opening `<form>` and a closing `</form>` tag. So your `fname` and `lname` will be ignored. (Your closing `</form>` is missing, too.)

**Why do you have to add your form elements between form tags?** This allows you to add multiple forms to one page. To identify which element contains to which form, they have to be between the form tags.

Example "Login & register on the same site":

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
   User: <input type="text" name="username">
   Password: <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<form method="POST" action="register.php">
   Mail: <input type="text" name="email">
   User: <input type="username" name="username">
   Password: <input type="password" name="password">
   Repeat password: <input type="password" name="pwdagain">
   <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Refer this site for further information: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: what should I do to use multiple forms under 1 submit button?

Comment: Just make one form of them. Each submit button belongs to one form, only. Otherwise you have to use JavaScript to copy one form's contents to the other form's contents.

Answer (score 0):

First name and last name will not post. Username and password will post but u have to close form tag first.

Comment: how can I use 2 forms with 1 submit button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096515/how-to-submit-2-forms-in-one-page-with-a-single-submit-button

Answer (score 0):

If you transform you code like this it will post all :

```
<input type="text" name="fname" form="my_form_id"> // First Name
<input type="text" name="lname" form="my_form_id"> // Last Name

<form id="my_form_id" method="post" action="#">   // Post 
<input type="text" name="username"> // Username
<input type="text" name="password"> // Password
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> // Submit Button
</form>
```

Comment: do I have to do anything with css with that id element? or its just as an identifier for both forms to be same...

Comment: This is not supported by IE yet, see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp

Comment: Nothing to do in CSS but like André said that not supported in IE -.-
http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute

Comment: any solution for IE..?

Answer (score 0):

There is some news on this front, it seems.

[MDN](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Element/Input.html) has this for you to review

form HTML5

"The form element that the input element is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be an id of an  element in the same document. If this attribute is not specified, this  element must be a descendant of an  element. This attribute enables you to place  elements anywhere within a document, not just as descendants of their form elements."

Perhaps you can still achieve what you wished for.  Only question then, is what browser support you must have.

Answer (score 0):

@shubham-jha If you want multiple submit buttons under a single form, you may use AJAX.

Create a JavaScript function on click, decide to which URL you want to send this data and then change form action using jQuery, then submit using JavaScript.

[Jquery to change form action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451600/jquery-to-change-form-action)

Comment: I think you misunderstood.. I do not want multiple submit buttons under 1 form.. Instead I want multiple Forms under 1 submit button.,..